# How to parse parameters from POST body to map[string] string?

Tags: go

How to parse parameters from `POST` body to `map[string] string`?

I am using gin and I can parse to predefined structure but in this case I don't know key names.
( I can when I know key names but when I don't know is a problem )

```
type Body struct {
    Name    string
    Email   string
}

body := Body{}
err := json.NewDecoder( c.Request.Body ).Decode( &body )
if err != nil {
    c.String( http.StatusServiceUnavailable, err.Error() )
    return
}
```

The body looks like this:

```
{ 
"param1": "1", 
"param2": "1", 
"param3": "1", 
"param4": "1" 
}
```

Comment: How does the POST body look like? Please provide a sample.

Comment: Standard body key, value parameters but I don't know keys. ( In python is easy because I can convert to dict whatever I want but in go I don;t know how when don't know names and number of keys)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a sample of this body. Please also include the code you have tried to parse it.

Comment: @LutzHorn I've edited

Comment: You write "Standard body key, value parameters" but you try to use a JSON decoder. Is the body of the request JSON?

Comment: @LutzHorn Yes, key value in json

Comment: Third and last time: Please [edit] your question and provide a sample of the JSON body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80282/discussion-between-paolaj-and-lutz-horn).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)


func main() {
    j := `{"foo": "aa", "baz": "bb", "qux": "cc"}`
    byt := []byte(j)

    var dat map[string]string   

    if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dat)
}
```

Output:

```
map[qux:cc foo:aa baz:bb]
```

<kbd>[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hQt7-caFCb)</kbd>